# AngularJs - ng-view does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-view

The ng-view directive does not work. All I see at the is the "Page "title. What is the problem?

https://jsfiddle.net/dsgfdyp1/3/

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Page

```
<div ng-view>  </div>
```

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config('routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

```
$routeProvider
.when("/", {templateUrl : "/home"});
```

});

Comment: Please put a minimal working code. You can include a jsFiddle link.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dsgfdyp1/3/

Comment: ```app``` is undefined, should be ```myApp``` I think?

Comment: yes, I didn't notice. but it did not solve the problem https://jsfiddle.net/r30tdmqk/2/

Comment: `app.config('routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {` ==> `app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {` AND `});` ==> `}]);` (When you close the `config` phase declaration) https://jsfiddle.net/dsgfdyp1/5/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `routeProvider` from  `myApp.config('routeProvider', function($routeProvider)`

As Shown below

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {templateUrl : "/templates/main.htm"});
  });
```

Solution based on $inject

```
myApp.config(routerConfig);

routerConfig.$inject =["$routeProvider"];

function routerConfig($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {templateUrl : "/templates/main.htm"});
      }
```

Comment: Why removing it? So they won't be able to minify their code? This is not a good solution (Although it will work, that's why I don't downvote it)

Comment: if you are concerned with minification, which I don't think in this case ( my bad). I will rewrite the code using $inject;

Comment: Please note that they can also fix it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dsgfdyp1/5/ (I'll upvote when you'll address the minification part because it's clearly visible from the code that the OP is taking that into account - Failing to correctly use the dependencies list to be injected to the relevant scope)

Comment: I tried both, With removing the first argument and adding square brackets, niether are working.

Comment: @AntonKuznetsov I added a link to a fiddle that worked for me, it wasn't just the wrong use of the array but also injecting `routeProvider` instead of `$routeProvider` (Note the missing **$**). But you should try this answer and accept it if it solve your issue because it _should_ work

Comment: It worcked! Thank you!